# How to convert my column into row using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have result my data frame as below. How to convert into rows. My column header is numbers which has to avoided

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvwVD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
row = [*'ABCDE']
row2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

df = pd.DataFrame([row,row2])
print(df)
```

Input dataframe:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  A  B  C  D  E
1  1  2  3  4  5
```

Use this code:

```
df_out = df.T.set_index(0)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   1
0   
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple reshape to do this.

This can be many other ways to do this, Here I show I way,

I think this is how your data frame looks like:

```
**df = pd.DataFrame({0:['neg',0.015],1:['neu',0.006],2:['pos',0.014]})**
```

You can do a simple reshape using below line:
  **

```
import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.iloc[1:]).reshape(-1,1))
```

**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to turn your first row into your header?

This is the way I would do it:

`df.T.set_index(0).T`